# python __init_subclass__ not called for all subclasses

Tags: python

I have an issue with `__init_subclass__` which is not called for all subclasses.

Here is my parent class:

```
@dataclass
class State:
    _STATE_CLASSES: ClassVar[Dict[str, Type]] = {}

    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        State._STATE_CLASSES[cls.__name__] = cls
```

Then I have multiple classes that extend this one at one or two levels of depth. Some are detected, some others no. And I can't figure out why. What is the rational behind this?

Example: Pass is detected while Fail and Choice are not

```
# detected
@dataclass
class Pass(State):
    type: str = States.Pass
    parameters: dict = None
    result_path: str = None
    result: str = None
    next: str = None
    end: bool = None

# not detected
@dataclass
class Choice(State):
    type: str = States.Choice
    choices: List[ChoiceRule] = dataclasses.field(default_factory=list)
    default: str = None

@dataclass
class Fail(State):
    type: str = States.Fail
    cause: str = None
    error: str = None
```

And if there is a cleaner way to get this _STATE_CLASSES dict of classes, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: It's going to be hard to solve this issue without examples of the problem in the form of `State` subclasses that don't get the method called on them. Can you make a [mcve]? Are you using any metaclass stuff anywhere in your class hierarchy? Do you have other `__init_subclass__` methods anywhere?

Comment: Added some subclasses (nothing fancy). I don't know what metaclass is, not using it. And no other `__init_subclass__` elsewhere.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue with the classes you've shown (after making some minor changes, since they're not entirely self-contained). After defining the three subclasses, I see all three in `State._STATE_CLASSES`. We need an example that reproduces the issue. Or maybe a better description of the issue, if *you* still see it happening with only the code you've shown us.

Comment: OK, found something. I have each class in separate files. When moving the different classes in the same file (where State is declared), they are detected. Isn't it possible to have separate files for different classes? (I'm a newbie in python)

Comment: You certainly *can* put classes in their own modules, though there's generally no specific *need* to do so in Python (which can be very shocking to people used to Java). Can you turn the situation you've found into a [mcve]? Show us exactly what files to make (including the relevant import statements), and then tell us what doesn't work. Make sure the problem still reproduces in your example scenario, you might want to try copying the code into a separate folder to test with (which can be a useful troubleshooting technique for you as well as making an example for the rest of us).